# Shade 'out-of bounds' area of plot with with geom_abline

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, graphics

I have a simple ggplot figure which looks like this -

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=n, y=n_e, colour = itt, linetype = itt)) +
  # stat smooth for the lines only (using glm, y ~ x)
  geom_smooth(method = glm, se=F) +
  # tweak defaults a little
  update_geom_defaults("smooth", list(size = 0.7)) + 
  # manually tweak colors/linetype
  scale_colour_manual(values=c("Black","Black")) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c("solid","dashed"))+
  geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope = 1, color="red", 
              linetype="dotted", size=0.8)
```

Because I haven't included any dummy data, here's what it looks like.

the area behind the dotted red abline is out of bounds (i.e. my data cannot fall behind it as y is constrained by x).

I'd like to plot a series of fine horizontal lines every 0.1 along the y axis to shade this area. The line slope is 1, so x1 = y1, x2 = y2 ect.

How can I generate the data to plot the lines, and add it my existing plot.

thanks
Jamie [image: a plot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear why you *didn't* include any dummy data. This makes reproducing your plot a bit harder. The following is an attempt to do so.

```r
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(x = 0, y = c(0, 0, -0.2),
                 xend = c(3, 22, 22), yend = c(3, 3, 2.2),
                 lty = 3:1,
                 col = c("red", "black", "black"))

p <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y, color = col, linetype = lty)) +
  geom_segment(aes(xend = xend, yend = yend)) +
  scale_color_identity() +
  scale_linetype_identity()

p
```

[image]

That's actually the hard part. The lines are pretty straightforward - just a single `geom_segment` call will suffice:

```r
p + geom_segment(
  data = data.frame(x = 0, y = seq(0, 3, 0.06)),
  aes(xend = y, yend = y), color = "red", size = 0, linetype = 1
)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-11-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Following on from Allan's answer,

I bumped into a few errors, but this works

```
 + geom_segment(data = data.frame(x = 0, y = seq(0, 3.5, 0.06)),
  aes(x = y, xend = x, y = y, yend = y), color = "red", size = 0.5, linetype = 1, inherit.aes = FALSE)
```

Comment: Hi Jamie. You just unaccepted my answer. Is there something you need me to change in it?

Comment: hi Allan - I couldn't get your answer to work with the code you provided, it needed the x&y to be specified and the ihenert.aes to be set to false.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't appreciate that, but I do appreciate the effort. Like lots of users here, I'm still feeling my way through some the basics.

Comment: No problem Jamie. Thanks. It's a great place to learn - I'm still learning every day.